# Powershell- Convert Complex XML to CSV

Tags: xml, powershell, csv

I want to convert the below XML to CSV. Though it has header line information in the XML file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<myfile>
  <updatetime>2019-07-30 08:30:30</updatetime>
  <process code="PRS1234" name="PROCESS1234" />
  <equipment code="EQP1234" name="EQUIPMENT1234" />
  <product type="equipment" planned="300" time="36000" cycletime="20" />
  <shift code="1" timestart="2019-07-30 02:00:00">
    <order index="1" goodproduct="500" defectproduct="5" time="2019-07-30 02:00:00" />
    <order index="2" goodproduct="980" defectproduct="7" time="2019-07-30 03:00:00" />
    <order index="3" goodproduct="1200" defectproduct="12" time="2019-07-30 04:00:00" />
    <order index="4" goodproduct="1800" defectproduct="15" time="2019-07-30 05:00:00" />
    <order index="5" goodproduct="2500" defectproduct="15" time="2019-07-30 06:00:00" />
  <shift>
  <shift code="2" timestart="2019-07-30 07:00:00">
    <order index="1" goodproduct="600" defectproduct="5" time="2019-07-30 07:00:00" />
    <order index="2" goodproduct="980" defectproduct="7" time="2019-07-30 08:00:00" />
    <order index="3" goodproduct="1500" defectproduct="8" time="2019-07-30 09:00:00" />
    <order index="4" goodproduct="1700" defectproduct="11" time="2019-07-30 10:00:00" />
    <order index="5" goodproduct="3000" defectproduct="15" time="2019-07-30 11:00:00" />
  </shift>
</myfile>
```

I can get values for the desired nodes. This is what I have done.

```
[xml]$inputFile = Get-Content "Q:\XML\FileComplex.xml"
$inputFile.myfile.product | Select-Object -Property type,planned,time,cycletime | ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation -Delimiter ";" | Set-Content -Path "Q:\XML\FileComplex.csv" -Encoding UTF8 "
```

What I'm trying to achieve is to combine all desired information together and to get it as one record of the CSV file, which is like this

```
updatetime          | code(process) | name(process) | code(equipment) | name(equipment) | type(product) | planned(product) | time(product) | cycletime(product) | goodproduct(shift(code) is 1 and index is max) | defectproduct(shift(code) is 1 and index is max) | goodproduct(shift(code) is 2 and index is max) | defectproduct((shift(code) is 2 where index is max)
2019-07-30 08:30:30 | PRS1234       | PROCESS1234   | EQP1234         | EQUIPMENT1234   | equipment     | 300              | 36000         | 20                 |                               2500             |                                               15 |                                           3000 |                                       15
```

I really appreciate your support!!

Thanks in advance
Natasha

Comment: Please post a sample of your *actual* XML, or fix the errors in the current sample so that it actually becomes loadable.

Comment: sorry, I fixed them @Tomalak

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would solve this using `SelectSingleNode()` and XPath.

```
$data = New-Object xml;
$data.load(".\myfile.xml")

$record = [pscustomobject]@{
    "updatetime"             = $data.SelectSingleNode("/*/updatetime")."#text"
    "code(process)"          = $data.SelectSingleNode("/*/process").code
    "name(process)"          = $data.SelectSingleNode("/*/process").name
    "code(equipment)"        = $data.SelectSingleNode("/*/equipment").code
    "name(equipment)"        = $data.SelectSingleNode("/*/equipment").name
    "type(product)"          = $data.SelectSingleNode("/*/product").type
    "planned(product)"       = $data.SelectSingleNode("/*/product").planned
    "time(product)"          = $data.SelectSingleNode("/*/product").time
    "cycletime(product)"     = $data.SelectSingleNode("/*/product").cycletime
    "goodproduct(shift 1)"   = $data.SelectSingleNode("/*/shift[@code = 1]/order[not(@index < ../order/@index)]").goodproduct
    "defectproduct(shift 1)" = $data.SelectSingleNode("/*/shift[@code = 1]/order[not(@index < ../order/@index)]").defectproduct
    "goodproduct(shift 2)"   = $data.SelectSingleNode("/*/shift[@code = 2]/order[not(@index < ../order/@index)]").goodproduct
    "defectproduct(shift 2)" = $data.SelectSingleNode("/*/shift[@code = 2]/order[not(@index < ../order/@index)]").defectproduct
}

$record
#$record | ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Explanation of `order[not(@index < ../order/@index)]`: *"Any `<order>` whose `index` is not less than the `index` of any other `<order>` next to it."* - The only `<order>` for which this condition is true is the one with the max `index`.

Output is like this (before conversion to CSV)

```
updatetime             : 2019-07-30 08:30:30
code(process)          : PRS1234
name(process)          : PROCESS1234
code(equipment)        : EQP1234
name(equipment)        : EQUIPMENT1234
type(product)          : equipment
planned(product)       : 300
time(product)          : 36000
cycletime(product)     : 20
goodproduct(shift 1)   : 2500
defectproduct(shift 1) : 15
goodproduct(shift 2)   : 3000
defectproduct(shift 2) : 15
```

Comment: one more question
Can you tell me how can I save this file as--> date(updatetime)-code(equipment).csv
which is like 2019-07-30-EQP1234.csv

Comment: You can see how `updatetime` and `equipment` are selected from the XML in my code. You should be able to build a filename from those two things. Use the `Export-Csv` cmdlet to write the CSV file.

Answer (score 2):

OP's XML doesn't appear to be valid. Assuming the XML is meant to be...

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<myfile>
    <updatetime>2019-07-30 08:30:30</updatetime>
    <process code="PRS1234" name="PROCESS1234" />
    <equipment code="EQP1234" name="EQUIPMENT1234" />
    <product type="equipment" planned="300" time="36000" cycletime="20" />
    <shift code="1" timestart="2019-07-30 02:00:00">
        <order index="1" goodproduct="500" defectproduct="5" time="2019-07-30 02:00:00" />
        <order index="2" goodproduct="980" defectproduct="7" time="2019-07-30 03:00:00" />
        <order index="3" goodproduct="1200" defectproduct="12" time="2019-07-30 04:00:00" />
        <order index="4" goodproduct="1800" defectproduct="15" time="2019-07-30 05:00:00" />
        <order index="5" goodproduct="2500" defectproduct="15" time="2019-07-30 06:00:00" />
    </shift>
    <shift code="2" timestart="2019-07-30 07:00:00">
        <order index="1" goodproduct="600" defectproduct="5" time="2019-07-30 07:00:00" />
        <order index="2" goodproduct="980" defectproduct="7" time="2019-07-30 08:00:00" />
        <order index="3" goodproduct="1500" defectproduct="8" time="2019-07-30 09:00:00" />
        <order index="4" goodproduct="1700" defectproduct="11" time="2019-07-30 10:00:00" />
        <order index="5" goodproduct="3000" defectproduct="15" time="2019-07-30 11:00:00" />
    </shift>
</myfile>
```

Because PowerShell's XPath 1.0 doesn't support the `max()` function the following code assumes that the `order` elements are arranged in ascending `index` order and just selects the last one. If you can't guarantee the `index` order you'll need to come up with your own `max()` solution...

```bsh
[xml]$xml = Get-Content "FileComplex.xml"

# PowerShell uses XPath 1.0, which doesn't support max().
# If it did, you could select: //shift[code=1]/order[@id = max(//shift[code=1]/order/@id)]
$order1 = $xml.SelectSingleNode("//shift[@code=1]/order[last()]")
$order2 = $xml.SelectSingleNode("//shift[@code=2]/order[last()]")

# Using Add-Member like this is messy, but guarantees the order of fields on the $result object...
$result = New-Object PSObject -Property $props
$result | Add-Member NoteProperty "updatetime" $xml.SelectSingleNode("//updatetime").InnerText
$result | Add-Member NoteProperty "code(process)" $xml.SelectSingleNode("//process").code
$result | Add-Member NoteProperty "name(process)" $xml.SelectSingleNode("//process").name
$result | Add-Member NoteProperty "code(equipment)" $xml.SelectSingleNode("//equipment").code
$result | Add-Member NoteProperty "name(equipment)" $xml.SelectSingleNode("//equipment").name
$result | Add-Member NoteProperty "type(product)" $xml.SelectSingleNode("//product").type
$result | Add-Member NoteProperty "planned(product)" $xml.SelectSingleNode("//product").planned
$result | Add-Member NoteProperty "time(product)" $xml.SelectSingleNode("//product").time
$result | Add-Member NoteProperty "cycletime(product)" $xml.SelectSingleNode("//product").cycletime
$result | Add-Member NoteProperty "goodproduct(shift(code) is 1 and index is max)" $order1.goodproduct
$result | Add-Member NoteProperty "defectproduct(shift(code) is 1 and index is max)" $order1.defectproduct
$result | Add-Member NoteProperty "goodproduct(shift(code) is 2 and index is max)" $order2.goodproduct
$result | Add-Member NoteProperty "defectproduct(shift(code) is 2 and index is max)" $order2.defectproduct

$result | Export-Csv -Path "FileComplex.csv" -Delimiter ';' -Encoding utf8
```

Comment: I don't think this fulfills the "index is max" condition...? It can be done using XPath 1.0, though.

Comment: You are right, it is not max(). And I said as much in my answer.

Comment: `($xml.SelectNodes("//shift[@code=1]/order") | Sort index | Select -Last 1)` would have been one of the alternatives.

Comment: Yes, that would totally work. I never understood why Microsoft didn't go beyond XPath 1.0 in their XMLDocument implementation. It's really quite limiting.

Comment: Me neither. At some point they simply stopped investing into XML.

Answer (score 2):

This is what I get finally

```
$data = New-Object xml;
$data.load("Q:\XML\Myfile.xml")
$record = [pscustomobject]@{
"updatetime"             = $data.SelectSingleNode("/*/updatetime")."#text"
"code(process)"          = $data.SelectSingleNode("/*/process").code
"name(process)"          = $data.SelectSingleNode("/*/process").name
"code(equipment)"        = $data.SelectSingleNode("/*/equipment").code
"name(equipment)"        = $data.SelectSingleNode("/*/equipment").name
"type(product)"          = $data.SelectSingleNode("/*/product").type
"planned(product)"       = $data.SelectSingleNode("/*/product").planned
"time(product)"          = $data.SelectSingleNode("/*/product").time
"cycletime(product)"     = $data.SelectSingleNode("/*/product").cycletime
"goodproduct(shift 1)"   = $data.SelectSingleNode("/*/shift[@code = 1]/order[not(@index < ../order/@index)]").goodproduct
"defectproduct(shift 1)" = $data.SelectSingleNode("/*/shift[@code = 1]/order[not(@index < ../order/@index)]").defectproduct
"goodproduct(shift 2)"   = $data.SelectSingleNode("/*/shift[@code = 2]/order[not(@index < ../order/@index)]").goodproduct
"defectproduct(shift 2)" = $data.SelectSingleNode("/*/shift[@code = 2]/order[not(@index < ../order/@index)]").defectproduct
}
$equipment = $record.'code(equipment)'
$date = Get-Date -Date $record.updatetime
$dateformat = $date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
$record | ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation -Delimiter ',' | Set-Content -Path "Q:\XML\$( "$equipment" + "_" + "$dateformat").csv" -Encoding utf8
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing your final solution!